# Using a scope in a Joins in AR

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, scope

Didn't find an answer for this in previous questions..

I have a scope in a model A

```
A.activated
```

which does pretty complex queries and joins, but it works properly.

I want to join A to B table as a LEFT OUTER JOIN but only the rows in A that are in the scope

`B.joins(:c).joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN a ON a.some_column = c.some_other_column")` <--- how to add the scope?

Comment: in class B `scope :activated, lambda{ joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN a ON a.some_column = c.some_other_column").joins(:c) }`

Comment: You should add the right answer or validate the one that helped you

Comment: have yet to find an answer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer is the fabulous `#merge`, don't leave home with it!

```
B.joins(:c).joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN a ON a.some_column = c.some_other_column").merge(A.activated)
```

Ta da!